# Visual Composer 4.12 and Firefox issue

Tags: wordpress, firefox, visual-composer

When adding multiple margin settings in rows along with IDs per row on a single page causes Firefox to crash on both Mac and PCs. The pages attempt to load but cause FF to lock up and I cannot generate a crash report to further investigate. This has been tested on multiple machines and different versions of FF on both Mac and PC.

Current versions 
WP 4.5.3
VC 4.12

The setup was intended to use a scroll to ID via a href. The additional settings for rows were only Margin Top and Bottom.  I reverted back to the  twentyfifteen  theme and only turned on Visual composer to determine if the issue was related. During this test FF again locked up. I have been able to resolve the issue by setting custom classes for row margins while still using Row IDs (this was a lucky stumble upon to resolve the issue).

Comment: Uninstall all the add-ons and then check it. Few days ago i feel a issue with VC and a FF add-ons issue.

Comment: I did that. Like I said, I rolled back to only the base WP theme and Visual Composer to check if that margin / row ID was the issue.